# How can I build an MSI installer from a UWP application?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

My company built a UWP application on behalf of a client. We have always distributed this application via the Microsoft Store for Business. Recently, our customer received an email that says, "Microsoft Store for Business will be retiring in the first quarter of 2023."

The customer asked us if we could distribute the app as a stand-alone MSI installer instead. I have no experience building this kind of installer and I'm not even sure it's possible to do so with a UWP application. I reached out to a company called Setup Factory which was recommended to me by a friend, but they told me their software cannot work with UWP applications.

I also tried a couple of free Visual Studio extensions, but they were difficult to use and neither of them was able to successfully build any kind of installer.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, what's the best approach? If not, what's the best alternative?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 1):

> The customer asked us if we could distribute the app as a stand-alone MSI installer instead.

Sure, UWP support creating MSIX package using Visual Studio, you could refer to [Package a desktop or UWP app in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps) document for detail steps. And you could easily [install the package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#install-your-app-package-using-an-install-script) by run Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 with powershell.

Comment: Thanks for the response. These instructions are showing me how to create an app package for sideloading with a self-signed certificate, which I already know how to do. Such a package can't be installed unless the user installs my certificate first. How do I create a package that can be installed anywhere? I assume I need a certificate that is not self-signed. How do I make one?

Comment: The better ways is deliver package and certificate to the user, and deloy the packge with powershell script, it will install the cer automatically. currently there is no such way could install the package without cer.

Comment: If you're publishing your app in Microsoft Store, your app will be signed with a trusted certificate for you. This allows the user to install and run your app without installing the associated app signing certificate.

Comment: I don't understand why I can't create a package that anyone can install without a certificate. I download and install Windows applications all the time without installing certificates. Could I not just substitute a trusted certificate for the self-signed certificate when I create the package?

Comment: @Flarosa you don't have to use the self-signed certificate, but you will need to get yourself an EV code signing certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. We'll work on getting the EV certificate.